# Why does Django file upload throws a IOError (2, 'No such file or directory') exception?

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms, django-views

I'm writing a simple file uploader for a website. The user sees a form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploader/" name="upload" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="datafile" size="20">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <span class="whats_this">Maximum File Size is 100 MB</span>
  <button class="button orange" type="start_upload" value="Submit" onclick="document.upload.submit() ">Start Upload</button>
  <span class="cancel_button"><a href="#">Cancel</a></span>     
</form>
```

and upon submit, I redirect to this function:

```
def uploadFiles(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':    
     if(validate(request)):
        file = request.FILES['datafile']

        destination = open('uploadedFiles/test.txt', 'wb+')

        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()

        context = {'files': file.name}
        return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context)
    else:
        ...
```

When I try this functionality out, I'll always get an exception:

```
IOError at /uploader/
(2, 'No such file or directory')
uploader\views.py in uploadFiles, line 17
```

Line 17 is the line of the destination "destination = open('uploadedFiles/test.txt', 'wb+')". I've been trying this out quite a bit but it simply doesn't work. Am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say where you're trying to upload to, or where you've created the `uploadedFiles` directory. The problem is that you're giving a relative path, but it's far from obvious where it is relative to - probably the `manage.py` or `.wsgi` file that's serving your site.

Give an absolute path, which for best results should be under `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. The issue was the path. I checked os.getcwd() and figured that I was missing a folder "/project" before the /uploader/...

Comment: @phmulin: feel free to accept Daniel's answer (click checkmark). That lets others know that your question has been addressed, and that you appreciate the assistance.